# Cannot read property 'type' of undefined (react-router-redux)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-router-redux, redux-observable

I am trying to redirect to the page after signing out. However, every time when I sign out, it directs the page successfully. However, I still got the error

> Cannot read property 'type' of undefined

Further research by "Pause on Caught Exceptions", it is related with **react-router-redux**.

[image]

So the line `store.dispatch(push('/signin'))` in the code below causes the issue. If I change to `.map(() => ({ type: 'NOT_EXIST' }));`, there will be no issue.

What may cause this? Thanks

**actions/auth.action.js**

```
export const signOutSucceedEpic = (action$, store) =>
  action$
    .ofType(SIGN_OUT_SUCCEED)
    .map(() => store.dispatch(push('/signin')));  // <- this line causes the issue
```

**actions/index.js**

```
import { combineEpics } from 'redux-observable';

export default combineEpics(
  // ...
  signOutSucceedEpic
);
```

**index.js**

```
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { ConnectedRouter, routerMiddleware, push } from 'react-router-redux';
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';
import rootEpic from './actions/index';

const history = createHistory();
const routeMiddleware = routerMiddleware(history);
const epicMiddleware = createEpicMiddleware(rootEpic);

export const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  persistedState,
  composeWithDevTools(
    applyMiddleware(
      epicMiddleware,
      routeMiddleware
    )
  )
);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
      <div>
        <Route path="/signin" component={SignIn} />
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
      </div>
    </ConnectedRouter>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: i think you forgot to specify the type, write it like this: `store.dispatch({type: 'abc', data: push('/signin')});` check the [**DOC**](http://redux.js.org/docs/api/Store.html#example) example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is you're calling `store.dispatch` inside a `map` operator, mapping to the return value of that `store.dispatch()` but it doesn't return anything, so the value `undefined` is getting emitted by your epic and then dispatched by redux-observable on your behalf. Then react-router-redux receives that `undefined` value but it assumes only actions with a `type` property will be dispatched, so it causes the error in question.

I recommend re-examining the redux-observable docs as calling `store.dispatch` directly inside your epics is an anti-pattern, and not necessary. Your epic should emit a stream of actions that will be dispatched for you by redux-observable, so in this case you could just remove the `store.dispatch` and instead map to the result of the `push()` action:

```
export const signOutSucceedEpic = (action$, store) =>
  action$
    .ofType(SIGN_OUT_SUCCEED)
    .map(() => push('/signin'));
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! Just put correct code here `.map(() => push('/signin'));`

Comment: You're writing some nonsense. `push('/signin')` indeed returns `undefined`. Look here http://engineering.blogfoster.com/higher-order-components-theory-and-practice/ and explain with your theory why `dispatch(push('/signin'));` works fine in that example and throws in OP's issue.

Comment: @Green this answer fixed his particular issue. Calling `push` from `react-router-redux` does not return `undefined`, it returns an action that you dispatch. Calling dispatch directly with it will indeed cause the transition, but you will receive the same error the OP did if you do it inside `map` because your epic should always emit actions, not `undefined`. Using `store.dispatch` directly inside epics is an anti-pattern and will be removed in v1.0.0 of redux-observable to prevent confusion. Instead, epics should emit actions that the middleware will dispatch for you.

Comment: I had a similar issue. Turns out I was calling a method connected to the dispatcher that didn't return an action (it was dispatching other actions but none itself). Un-connecting that method solved my problem.